# Animating ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am building a carousel by shifting an element from the start of an array then pushing it back to the end making the carousel advanced. Popping an element off the end of an array and unshifting it onto the start of the array will rewind the element. This works fine. The trouble arises when I try and animate it.

ng-repeat items are supposed to broadcast a 'move' event when their position changes in the repeat list. However it appears only certain items in the repeat list fire a move event when their index has changed.

Check out my Plunker for an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/PxeTeqks9sXNM4d2lE79?p=preview

When you click "shift - push" all but the last number animates. Clicking "pop - unshift" animates only the first number.

I would think when every item in the repeat list has it's indexed changed all of the items should fire move events. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

The animation has changed in significant in Angular 1.2. You should definitely consider switching to 1.2 or higher in case you are not already using it.

Now you have to include the angular-animate.js file since the core of AngularJS does not support animations anymore. Basically the old ngAnimate directive is now deprecated. Instead you can animate everything with pure CSS.

For you it means you can declare some CSS styles for .ng-enter, .ng-leave and .ng-move to animate the items in your ng-repeat. For examples check out the following link:

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-ngrepeat

Check the Plunker example here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview